# Generate UI objects UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have app that can make collages. User pick some pictures and use it on Page. Now I have hardcoded 6 images in `Xaml` userControl, and 6 properties for Binding in VM. Can I optimize that? That user can pick different amount of pictures and work with them? Now I use `List`

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> collageimages
```

to storage chosen pictures but then I use `for` to fill `UI` pictures

```
 for (var i = 0; i < collageimages.Count-1; i++)
        {
            var stream = await collageimages[i].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var bitmapImage = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: /*property in ViewModel*/
                    CollageImg1 = bitmapImage;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    CollageImg2 = bitmapImage;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    CollageImg3 = bitmapImage;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    CollageImg4 = bitmapImage;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    CollageImg5 = bitmapImage;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    CollageImg6 = bitmapImage;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But its not good code. How I can remove this `switch` and generate `Images`. I think about some `DataTemplate` but my implementation failed, and I need place this images at different position(at least slightly different)

UPD

Do you mean this?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < collageimages.Count; i++)
        {
            var stream = await collageimages[i].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            var bitmapImage = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            List<WriteableBitmap> imagesList[i] = bitmapImage;
         }
```

My property looks like

```
 public WriteableBitmap CollageImg1
    {
        get { return collageImg1; }
        set
        {
            this.collageImg1 = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("CollageImg1");
        }
    }
```

What I need to change?

Comment: I'm not understanding exactly, but couldn't you use a List<T> or Dictionary<int,T> rather than individual CollageImg(X)? With Dictionary, it would be myCollageDictionary[x] instead of CollageImgX

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger updated my question, check please

Comment: Yeah - assuming you've already instantiated imagesList[I] with an initial imagesList.Add(), then that's what I'm talking about. A Dictionary would give you significant performance advantages when dealing with much larger containers, but for 6 items, a List should be pretty easy to manage. Just remember they're not 1 through 6 anymore but 0 through 5

Comment: And how I put this List to my CollafeImageX properties?

Comment: imageList[0].MyProperty instead of CollageImg5.MyProperty

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I updated question

Comment: I'm guessing you need six different properties - change CollageImg1 to CollageImg, add a property for indexNumber (0-5) and now you reference each CollageImg using the same property with an index corresponding to the list index.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger could you give example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ItemControl and Datatemplate

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageManipulatorViewModel.ImageList, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Collage">
        <Image/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Observable Collections.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

You maybe should use a `GridView` instead of a `ListView` because a `ListView` is designed mainly for Holding text.

Add this Code to your MainPage:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CollectionViewSource"></CollectionViewSource>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then create a GridView like that:

```
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionViewSource}}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

In `MainPage.xaml.cs` write this:

```
        ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> images = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
        // TODO: FIll Collection with Images
        CollectionViewSource.Source = images;
```

Because the `ObservableCollection` is implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` the `GridView` should update when the user is adding some Images.

Comment: Oh, thanks, im try later. And can I write some method that generate pos.X and pos.Y and put it into some List or Collection and make Binding in DataTemplate?

Comment: @SmiLe You can create a `Model` (a simple class) like `CollectionImage` with the properties `Image` , `Position` and changing the type of the observable Collection to  `ObservableCollection<CollectionImage>` and then you can bind to your Position if you add e.g. a `<TextBlock></Textblock>` to the `DataTemplate` and wrap that into a grid